# Permalinks wordpress without Rewrite module

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use permalinks to change the url of the pages of my wordpress but my actual hosting doesn't allow me to activate an Apache module.

Is there a way to change the permalinks style without Rewrite module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well as @doublesharp said there isn't a way to do it.

If someone needs something similar this is what I finally did:

Set custom structure in your Permalink Settings and put this:

```
/index.php/%postname%/
```

This will create an structure like this: 
    http://youdomain.com/index.php/postname